# CSS border (':after') not expanding full width when the text is wrapped

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to add and animate a line under a link using `CCS` but the positioning of the line (or, perhaps, its width) breaks when the text wraps.

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve and what the problem is:

- normal behavior:

  [image]
- breaking:

  [image]

Here is the `fiddle` of the illustration: https://jsfiddle.net/b1zajhs5/. To make it break, just shrink the result panel until the text wraps.

This is the `HTML` used

```
<div class="centered">
  <a href="#"><span class="effect-underline">Some Text That Has to Be Quite Long To Prove the Point</span></a>
</div>
```

And this is the `SCSS`:

```
.centered {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 1.5rem .5rem;
  text-align:center;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


.effect-underline {
    position: relative;

  &:after {
        content: '';
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1em;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.35s;
        transform: scale(0, 1);
    }

    &:hover {
        &:after {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how the line can be expanded the match the full width of the link when the text is wrapped?

Comment: Have you tried using [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)? (not sure of the result, but `clone` might help)

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Tried it, same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.effect-underline` to make it go across when the text wraps.

```css
.centered {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.effect-underline {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.effect-underline:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
          transform: scale(0, 1);
}
.effect-underline:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <a href="#"><span class="effect-underline">Some Text That Has to Be Quite Long To Prove the Point</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: An explanation why `inline-block` does the trick would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why display: inline-block worked, was because a span, by default has a inline display. So, naturally, the line is going till the end of a text, and the end was on last sentence, that broke bellow.

giving it a display of inline-block, an element becomes like a block element, so the line goes till the end of a block, not the end of a sentence.